# Questions about data import from excel to mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a question about "Excel data import MySQL".

I first restored my data into CSV format, and then I used "Table Data import wizard" in MySQL to restore my table.

And I faced a problem here: I have a date column, which the format is mm/dd/yy, and when I used "Table Data import wizard", this column format was saved as the text type, not the date type. (**There is only text type and datetime type to choose**). And it have to save as text format, otherwise, it may show error. And the data looks well, and it showed mm/dd/yy as well in the Mysql table.

However, when I want to summary the data by month, I cannot run Month() statement, it is because this column is text format, not date format.

So, I want to find a way to transfer the data type from text to date, and it seems I cannot do it directly from the table, so does anyone who can help me with that?

Or can i manipulate this text type column to summarize the month report?

Any Idea Guys?

Thanks!

Comment: Mysql does not have a table import wizard. What gui are you using (phpmyadmin, mysqlworkbench, heidisql, toad?)

Comment: Have you checked str_to_date function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use STR_DO_DATE() function to convert your text data to date. In your example, you can use the following script to convert it:

`Select STR_TO_DATE(your_field_name, '%m/%d/%Y') from your_table`

You can then have option to use the script directly to your queries, or you can create a new date field on your table then just run the following script:

`Update your_table SET New_field=STR_TO_DATE(your_field_name, '%m/%d/%Y')`